# Как растянуть iframe на высоту всего его содержимого?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Добрый день! Как мы знаем, iframe позволяет загружать независимые данные в область заданных размеров блока. Размер блока может быть как точным в пикселях, так и в процентах. И если взять второй вариант, где нет фиксированной в px высоты, то тем не менее, если высота загружаемого документа будет больше, то у iframe или у блока (если overflow-y:scroll;) будет скроллинг.
Скажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли все-таки вариант, может быть с помощью javascript, принудительно растянуть iframe на всю высоту его содержимого? Спасибо!

```html
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://ru.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Экономический календарь от <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-events.js">
{
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "locale": "ru",
  "importanceFilter": "-1,0,1"
}
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9162933/2881286

Comment: У тебя, скорее всего, проблема будет на с тем, как найти нужный iframe, а с тем, что скорее всего не сможешь получить доступ к его внутренностям, чтобы измерить высоту.

Comment: Выводимый iframe можно будет растянуть, вызвав соответствующий скрипт, если будет доступ к его внутренностям.

Comment: Чтобы установить высоту iframe, который виджет загружается через javascript, ты должен дождаться окончания загрузки и узнать высоту контента этого iframe.